# Reaction of chloroform with DBU

Tags: organic-chemistry

There's a certain reaction I've been doing that involves DBU (I've drawn the structure out below). The reaction is done in a flow machine (ie. high temperature and high pressure).
[image]
I've read that chloroform can't be used as a solvent for this reaction, because under the flow machine conditions DBU reacts with chloroform to form a side product.
I was interested in what this reaction is, so I've had a bit of a look but can't work it out. Here's what I'm thinking so far:

1. I've read that chloroform can react with base to form dichlorocarbene. There's no strong base here in this reaction, but could the high temperature/pressure conditions be causing this species to form? Dichlorocarbene could then react with DBU.
2. The only alternative I can think of is that chloroform does a nucleophilic substitution (with the DBU acting as electrophile)? Under normal conditions chloroform doesn't do nucleophilic substitution, but maybe under high temperature/pressure conditions it can. Also, DBU could potentially act as an electrophile in different ways:
   [image]
   Or alternatively, the enamine tautomer could potentially be the nucleophile:
   [image]
   Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4):

DBU is stronger base than you think. Strong enough to generate dichlorocarbene from chloroform under flow conditions as this reference shows [here](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Qing-Wen-Song/publication/272131747_PEG400-enhanced_synthesis_of_gem-dichloroaziridines_and_gem-dichlorocyclopropanes_via_in_situ_generated_dichlorocarbene/links/5620947108aed8dd19404aa7/PEG400-enhanced-synthesis-of-gem-dichloroaziridines-and-gem-dichlorocyclopropanes-via-in-situ-generated-dichlorocarbene.pdf?origin=publication_detail).